# R - Median of a Frequency distribution, grouped by another variable

Tags: r, grouping, median

I have a data set that look like the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i8Cj.png

Name | State | Zipcode | County_name | average payment | Frequency

My desired output would be to group by State and have the Median payment using the average payment and Frequency columns.

I know how to do this for the overall dataset

```
median(rep(Clean$medicare_average_payment, Clean$Frequency))
```

but not sure how to do this by State
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sum a variable by group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)    
Clean1 <- Clean[rep(1:nrow(Clean), Clean$Frequency),]
Clean1 %>%
      group_by(State) %>%
      summarise(Median = median(medicare_average_payment))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Clean)[, .(Median = median(rep(medicare_average_payment, Frequency))) , State]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `by` to do split the data frame and perform this function on each piece:

```
by(Clean, Clean$State, 
   FUN=function(x) median(rep(x$medicare_average_payment, x$Frequency))
)
```